# Better way of getting the count of an object's property in a collection

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to get the count a particular property of an object appears in a collection. Here's the object

```
public class Candidate {
    public string Qualification {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Qualification can be 1 of 5 things, High School, Associates, Bachelors, Masters, and PhD

In this case, I want to see whether the same Qualification occurs more than once in a collection of candidates. Here's my method so far

```
public (string, int) GetQualificationCountAsync(List<Candidate> candidates)
{
    var roleCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (var candidate in candidates)
    {
        if (roleCount.ContainsKey(candidate.Qualification)) roleCount[candidate.Qualification] += 1;
        else roleCount[candidate.Qualification] = 1;
    }
    var maxCount = roleCount.Values.Max();
    if (maxCount <= 1) return (string.Empty, 0);
    var key = string.Empty;
    foreach (var keyValuePair in roleCount.Where(keyValuePair => EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(keyValuePair.Value, maxCount))) 
        key = keyValuePair.Key;
    
    return (key, maxCount);

}
```

Is there a cleaner way of retrieving this information?

Comment: How do you determine uniqueness... Do you want reference-equality or value-equality?

Comment: Your `GetQualificationCountAsync` method contains no async/`await` logic...

Comment: I'll update the question but the Qualification can be 1 of 5 things for each candidate, High School, Assossciates, Bachelors, Masters, and PhD

Comment: _"I want to see whether the same Qualification occurs more than once"_ - what if 2 or more `Qualification` values appear more than once?

Comment: You can do it in one line with `candidates.GroupBy( c => c.Qualification ).Where( grp => grp.Count() >= 2 ).Select( grp => ( qual: grp.Key, count: grp.Count() ) ).ToList();`

Comment: @Dai would you mind explaining that query? I'm a bit new to LINQ.

Comment: Is this for Linq-to-Objects or Linq-to-Entities?

Comment: uhh objects i guess?

Comment: It's going to group all of the entities with the same `Qualification` value together. Then it's going to through away any entries in that list that have less than two entries with the same Qual value. At that point, you have something like a dictionary, where the key is the Qual value, and the "value" is a list of entities with that value. Finally, it's going to walk through that collection and return a list that contains (Qualification, countOfThoseWithThatQual) pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one <del>line</del> statement like so:

```cs
public static List<( String qualification, Int32 count )> GetNondistinctQualifications( IEnumerable<Candidate> candidates )
{
    return candidates
        .GroupBy( c => c.Qualification )
        .Where( grp => grp.Count() >= 2 )
        .Select( grp => ( qual: grp.Key, count: grp.Count() ) )
        .ToList();
}
```

If it helps to explain it: if this were SQL, the equivalent would be:

(Remember in SQL, the logical order-of-operations is `FROM > WHERE > GROUP BY > HAVING > SELECT > ORDER BY`, which is why `COUNT(*)` is used twice, despite it being obviously redundant (blame the ISO commitee that designed SQL))

```sql
SELECT
    c.Qualification,
    COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM
    candidates AS c
GROUP BY
    c.Qualification
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: A dictionary would be better as return type :o)

Comment: @SirRufo Not necessarily - we don't know how the data will be consumed yet.

Comment: @Dai what would change if it were to be a dictionary instead?

Comment: @Spartan117 I can't say - you haven't told us how you want to consume the data that `GetNondistinctQualifications` returns.

Comment: Basically put a log that says a particular qualification occurs more than once and and log the names of the candidates that are part of that qualification.

Comment: In which case I see no advantage to using a `Dictionary` over a `List` here. Using a List-of-Tuples means you get meaningful names (`qual` and `count`) but using a `Dictionary<K,V>` means losing that self-documentation and having to manually document how the dict's entries' `Key` and `Value` properties represent those values).